# Can't create a new react-native project using npx react-native@latest init

Tags: react-native, npm, error-handling, expo, yarnpkg

I am relatively new to react-native. and also recently decided to dual boot ubuntu alongside windows 10 on my laptop. whenever I create a project in windows using the command npx react-native init , it works but in ubuntu  whenever I run npx react-native@latest init or npx react-native init
I encounter the ERROR:

```
⠋ Downloading templateerror Cannot parse yarn version: 
⠇ Downloading templateerror Cannot parse yarn version: 
✖ Downloading template
error Command failed with exit code 243: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest.
Error: Command failed with exit code 243: npm install --save --save-exact react-native@latest
    at makeError (/home/wmaximus/node_modules/execa/lib/error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (/home/wmaximus/node_modules/execa/index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async createFromTemplate (/home/wmaximus/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:96:5)
    at async Object.initialize [as func] (/home/wmaximus/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/init/init.js:184:3)
    at async Command.handleAction (/home/wmaximus/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:109:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I've already installed all dependencies needed:

```
sudo apt install nodejs
sudo apt install npm
sudo apt install defualt-jdk
```

Installed android studio and also the android SDK and all packages needed. Configured the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variables.

I have tried multiple answers I found of people encountering a similar error with no effect:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g yarn
```

Also tried using expo, but:

```
wmaximus@wmaximus-HP-Laptop-17z-ca000:~/Desktop$ npx expo init hello
Need to install the following packages:
expo@49.0.11
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.18.9: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

  $ expo init is not supported in the local CLI, please use npx create-expo-app instead
```

And when I try  `npx create-expo-app` :

```
npx create-expo-app projNeed to install the following packages:create-expo-app@2.1.1Ok to proceed? (y) y✖ Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files: Could not find npm package "expo-template-blank@latest"
```